# When i translate a shape it shows the opposite coordinates x and y

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

When I translate a shape in openGL it shows the shape in the wrong position. For example if I translate it by (-150 -150)

```
GLUT glut=new GLUT();
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslated(-150,-150,0);
glut.glutSolidCone(100f,100,10,10);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

it shows (editor: missing link to screenshot), but for

```
GLUT glut=new GLUT();
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslated(150,150,0);
glut.glutSolidCone(100f,100,10,10);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

it shows[image: screenshot]

The entire code is

```
import com.sun.opengl.util.Animator;
import com.sun.opengl.util.gl2.*;    //GLUT contain predefined shapes
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Template3D extends JFrame implements GLEventListener,KeyListener,MouseMotionListener,MouseListener{

    GLCanvas canvas;
    Animator a;
    double r=0;;
    double t=0;
    boolean right=true;
    boolean left=false;

    public Template3D(){
        canvas=new GLCanvas();
        a=new Animator(canvas);
        a.start();
        add(canvas);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable d){

        GL2 gl=d.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClearColor(1f,1f,1f,0);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glOrtho(400,-400,300,-300,400,-400);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);


    }
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable d){

        GL2 gl=d.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glColor3f(1,0,1);

        //predefined shapes
        GLUT glut=new GLUT();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslated(150,150,0);
        glut.glutSolidCone(100f,100,10,10);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    //  gl.glPushMatrix();
    //  gl.glTranslatef(150,150,0);
    //  glut.glutSolidTorus(100f,100,10,10);
    //  gl.glPopMatrix();

    }
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable d,int x,int y,int width,int high){}
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable d){}

    //KeyListener
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

    //MouseMotionListener
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseDroped(MouseEvent e){}

    //MouseListener
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}




    public static void main(String []dfg){
        Template3D sample=new Template3D();
        sample.setSize(800,600);
        sample.setVisible(true);
        sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sample.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the missing screenshot and describe better your problem because this way it's difficult to tell what you want

Comment: And, please, put your code in a separate and self contained file so that we can run it

Comment: The full code does not call `glTranslated()`, so I don't see how it's related to the problem description.

Comment: sorry iam poor in English 

now I have edited the question 
the question is now correct....

Comment: Next time, read the manual: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml I remind you that JOGL is a Java binding for the OpenGL (C) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptoms are caused by this call:

```
gl.glOrtho(400,-400,300,-300,400,-400);
```

The signature of `glOrtho()` is:

```
void glOrtho(GLdouble left, GLdouble right,
             GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top,  
             GLdouble nearVal, GLdouble farVal);
```

So your values are:

```
left:   400
right: -400
bottom: 300
top:   -300
```

With left being larger than right, your x-coordinate direction is right to left. And with bottom larger than top, the y-coordinate direction is top to bottom.

Therefore, if you translate your geometry with positive coordinate values, it will move to the left and down. Which is exactly what you're seeing.

If you want a more conventional coordinate system where x goes from left to right and y from bottom to top, your `glOrtho()` call should look like this:

```
gl.glOrtho(-400.0, 400.0, -300.0, 300.0, -400.0, 400.0);
```